# Proof for Conditional Variance relation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, variance

so I've been trying to prove the following relation for quite a while now but haven't really figured it out yet, maybe I'm missing something really obvious.

To prove:

$\frac{Var(E\left[X|Y\right])}{Var(X)} = \frac{Var(E[Y|X])}{Var(Y)}$

This problem seems to be related to the law of total Variance: 
$Var(X) = Var(E\left[X|Y\right]) + E\left[Var(X|Y)\right])$

So if you look at it in terms of the explained and unexplained parts the equation above basically states that the percentage of the Variance of X explained by Y is the same as the percentage of the Variance of Y explained by X which seems a bit odd to me.

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this problem? Or is there already a similar or related relation which can be used to proof this equation?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. You can get the proper font and spacing for $\operatorname{Var}$ using `\operatorname{Var}`.

Comment: One obvious condition for this equality to hold is that $\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y)>0$. Else a denominator is zero which leads to problems.

Answer (score 1):

The equality is not true in general and here is a counterexample. Let $(X,Y)$ has joint pmf
$$
\mathbb P(X=0,Y=0)=\frac14, \quad \mathbb P(X=0,Y=1)=\frac14, \quad \mathbb P(X=1,Y=-1)=\frac12.
$$
Then $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)=\frac12 \mathbb 1_{\{X=0\}}-\mathbb 1_{\{X=1\}}$, $\text{Var}(\mathbb E(Y\mid X))=\frac{9}{16}$, $\text{Var}(Y)=\frac{11}{16}$ and 
$$
\frac{\text{Var}(\mathbb E(Y\mid X))}{\text{Var}(Y)} = \frac{9}{11}.$$
And $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)=\mathbb 1_{\{Y=-1\}}$, $\text{Var}(\mathbb E(X\mid Y))=\frac{1}{4}$, $\text{Var}(X)=\frac{1}{4}$ and 
$$
\frac{\text{Var}(\mathbb E(X\mid Y))}{\text{Var}(X)} = 1.$$